# Understanding image size changes in DCGAN

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network, convolution

I have been studying and trying to implement Generative Adversarial Networks using PyTorch. More precisely I tried to replicate [the DCGAN PyTorch Tutorial](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/dcgan_faces_tutorial.html) tutorial using some custom dataset.

My code worked well and I was able to get some nice results, but when I look at the architecture of both the generator and the discriminator I struggle to understand how the image sizes change as it goes through the different convolutional layers. To make my question a bit more clear, I do not understand the process to go from the original noise vector of size 100 to the 64X64X3 output image in the below architecture:

```
class Generator(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, ngpu):
        super(Generator, self).__init__()
        self.ngpu = ngpu
        self.main = nn.Sequential(
            # input is Z, going into a convolution
            nn.ConvTranspose2d( nz, ngf * 8, 4, 1, 0, bias=False),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(ngf * 8),
            nn.ReLU(True),
            # state size. (ngf*8) x 4 x 4
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(ngf * 8, ngf * 4, 4, 2, 1, bias=False),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(ngf * 4),
            nn.ReLU(True),
            # state size. (ngf*4) x 8 x 8
            nn.ConvTranspose2d( ngf * 4, ngf * 2, 4, 2, 1, bias=False),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(ngf * 2),
            nn.ReLU(True),
            # state size. (ngf*2) x 16 x 16
            nn.ConvTranspose2d( ngf * 2, ngf, 4, 2, 1, bias=False),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(ngf),
            nn.ReLU(True),
            # state size. (ngf) x 32 x 32
            nn.ConvTranspose2d( ngf, nc, 4, 2, 1, bias=False),
            nn.Tanh()
            # state size. (nc) x 64 x 64
        )

    def forward(self, input):
        return self.main(input)
```

[image]

I checked some online resources as well as the PyTorch documentation, and I found some different formulas to calculate the output size of convolutional layers. However none of them were enough to explain the big transformations that occur in this particular architecture.

I hope someone here can help me understand this!